# add a new column with sum of columns in perl

Tags: perl

I have a huge text file which has below columns

```
col1 col2 Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
abc dec 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 11 12 13
```

The output I am looking for is an addition of all months in new column FullYear.

```
col1 col2 Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec FullYear
abc dec 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 11 12 13 486
```

I tried using awk command, however, my data is with huge precision numbers. And the below command is giving wrong output.

```
awk -F ' ' {print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8" "$9" "$10" "$11" "$12" "$13" "$14" "$3+$4+$5+$6+$7+$8+$9+$10+$11+$12+$13+$14}' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

I need to write a Perl script to get this done.

Comment: Define "wrong".  How is the `awk` script not working as expected?

Comment: The actual numbers in the file are with huge precision
13438.40828455529 14782.24911301082 14782.24911301082 14782.24911301082 14782.24911301082 14782.24911301082 14782.24911301082 14782.24911301082 14782.24911301082 14782.24911301082 14782.24911301082 14782.24911301082

when these numbers are added. It gives addition in unusual format.

Comment: That's not a probem; use `printf` to specify the format in which you want the results to be printed.  It's also helpful in your example input to use data which demonstrates the problem you're having.  By default it's probably using exponential notation; if you want fixed-point notation you can do something like `printf( "%5.10f", $6 )` to get five and ten places of output before and after the decimal point, respectively.

Comment: I want to add a new column to existing file.
awk -F ' ' {printf "%s %s %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %10.10f" , $1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" "$7" "$8" "$9" "$10" "$11" "$12" "$13" "$14" "$3+$4+$5+$6+$7+$8+$9+$10+$11+$12+$13+$14}' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt

Tried this, however it doesn't work.

Comment: Again, define "doesn't work".  How does it not function as expected or intended?  Please answer this question not by adding an additional comment, but by editing your question to include the relevant information.

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly easy to do in Perl, even as a one-liner:

```
perl -MList::Util=sum -anE 'if (1 == $.) { say join(q{ }, @F, q{FullYear}) } else { say join(q{ }, @F, sum(@F[2..13])) }' «YOUR-FILE»
```

Explanation:

`-MList::Util=sum` loads the List::Util module and imports the `sum` function. This is the same as `use List::Util qw(sum)`.

`-n` tells Perl to process the input file line-by-line, running the script for each line. (Actually redundant, as the next option implicitly turns this on). `-a` turns on autosplit mode, so we get an array `@F` with one entry per field. `-E` means we're going to provide a script as a command-line argument, using current Perl features (for "say" in this case).

Full details for those options can be found in the `perlrun` manpage/podfile.

Then, here is the script, with spacing added, and comments explaining:

```perl
if (1 == $.) {                        # $. is the line number. Line 1 is header line.
    say join(' ', @F, q{FullYear});   # print out the heder + FullYear
}
else {
    # print out rows + sum of columns 2..13. Remember Perl counts from 0 in arrays,
    # so column 2 is the 3rd column (the number for January).
    say join(' ', @F, sum(@F[2..13]));
}
```

BTW: You can ask Perl to help understand one-liners (at least ones you trust — this is not safe with untrusted scripts) with `-MO=Deparse`, which gives output like this:

command:

```
perl -MO=Deparse -MList::Util=sum -anE 'if (1 == $.) { say join(q{ }, @F, q{FullYear}) } else { say join(q{ }, @F, sum(@F[2..13])) }' t-file
```

output:

```perl
use List::Util (split(/,/, 'sum', 0));
use feature 'current_sub', 'bitwise', 'evalbytes', 'fc', 'postderef_qq', 'say', 'state', 'switch', 'unicode_strings', 'unicode_eval';
LINE: while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {
    our @F = split(' ', $_, 0);
    if (1 == $.) {
        say join(' ', @F, 'FullYear');
    }
    else {
        say join(' ', @F, &sum(@F[2..13]));
    }
}
-e syntax OK
```

So you can see the `List::Util` load, the `-n` going line-by-line, and `-a` adding the `split`.

Comment: This works if my numbers are up to 5 digits. 
However, it gives incorrect added numbers if my numbers are in 7 to 8 digits.

Answer (score 2):

Would `Math::BigFloat` do for your "huge precision"?

```
perl -MMath::BigFloat -ape 'my $s=0; $s += new Math::BigFloat($_) for @F[2..$#F]; s/$/ $s/'

abc dec 7.5 8.5
abc dec 7.5 8.5 16
```

You could also use `List::Util::sum` with `Math::BigFloat`; it's quite pointless, though:

```
perl -MMath::BigFloat -MList::Util=sum -ape 's/$/" ".sum map new Math::BigFloat($_), @F[2..$#F]/e'
```

Comment: Tried this approach. However, the results I am getting is NaN.
Not sure if I am missing something here.

perl -MMath::BigFloat -ape 'my $s=0; $s += new Math::BigFloat($_) for @F[4..15]; s/$/ $s/' input

Comment: that means that any of the fields from the **5th** to **16th** is not a number. Notice that in perl array indexes start from 0, as in C, not from 1 as in awk or Fortran.

Comment: @Parix In your awk script, you have `$3+...+$14`; that should translate to `@F[2..13]` in perl, not to `@F[4..15]`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not `perl`, but this seems to get the job done:

```
awk 'NR==1 {$(NF+1) = "FullYear"; print} NR>1 {subtotal=0; for(f=0;f<=NF; f++) {subtotal+=$f}; $(NF+1)=subtotal; printf( "%s %s %5.10f %5.10f %5.10f %5.10f %5.10f %5.10f %5.10f %5.10f %5.10f %5.10f %5.10f %5.10f %5.10f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15 ) }' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a variant of @derobert:

```
perl -MList::Util=sum -nlE 'say "$_ ", sum((split)[2..13])||"FullYear"' input
```

or using `-a`

```
perl -MList::Util=sum -nalE 'say "$_ ", sum(@F[2..13])||"FullYear"' input
```

Comment: Tries this approach too. This works if my numbers are up to 5 digits. 
However, it gives incorrect added numbers if my numbers are in 7 to 8 digits.

Comment: @Parix, could you please show me an example of such a situation?

Comment: Output for 2 records is as below:

  Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec FullYear
col11 col12 2298846.53 2328664.3 2326527.39 2385298.77 2400046.08 2404192.36 2394351.11 2415755.8 2383387.25 2410001.65 2388574.37 2387894.37 26135645.61
col21 col22 13438.40828 14782.24911 14782.24911 14782.24911 14782.24911 14782.24911 14782.24911 14782.24911 14782.24911 14782.24911 14782.24911 14782.24911 176043.1485



The #1 record <-- gives incorrect added value
The #2 record <-- gives correct added value

Comment: @Parix, with both variants, in my machine I get  not "26135645.61" but  "28523539.98"

Comment: hi.. seems my starting data columns are causing the issue. The calculation works where it's a single word. however, it is not considering the last column where in it's more than a single word.
Though my entire file is tab delimited with data identifier as double quotes "